# How to set a countdown timer with a start date to an end date?

Tags: jquery, date, datetime, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm using a [countdown plugin](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) but I want to create a future countdown start date > end date. For example if now [ `2015/05/16 00:00:00` ] I want to create start date [ `2015/06/16 00:00:00` ] to end date [ `2015/07/16 00:00:00` ] to show `div` content and also hide other `div` content before start date and after end date.

Also searched another plugins :

1. https://github.com/Reflejo/jquery-countdown
2. http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html
3. http://rendro.github.io/countdown/
4. https://github.com/tomgrohl/jCountdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code would only start the countdown when the actual day is between the start- and enddate and will work for the jQuery countdown.

```
<div id="element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var startdate = "2015/06/16",
        enddate = "2015/07/16";
    if(new Date() >= new Date(startdate) && new Date() <= new Date(enddate)) {
        $("#element")
        .countdown(enddate, function(event) {
            $(this).text(
                event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
            );
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you worked but one more think how to hide a div content using callback?